# Displaying in-database image on the map with ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have an SQL database that contains a table with a coordinate, as well as a blob that contains an image associated with that location, as well as other columns expressing the width and height (in mm) of the area represented by the image.

I'm trying to have these images displayed at their location on a map.

I have been able to connect ArcGIS to my database and add the table to the map, so right now, ArcGIS displays a point ("single symbol") at the coordinates it extracted from the table.

But I'd want it to display the image from the blob column instead, like I accomplished easily with QGIS.

In QGIS, it was as simple as:

- creating a layer from that database table.
- add a "raster image marker" (with `"'base64:'||to_base64(attribute('LayoutImage'))"` as the expression)
- set the "Width" to point to my "Width" column and select "milimeters" as the scale.

Done. All images display properly on the map.

But how to do that with ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question: I've had confirmation from ESRI that this is not a scenario they currently support.

-"I brought your inquiry up with my team today and we agreed that the closest Esri functionality to what you're looking for would be to create attachments to access your image attachments via the "Attributes" pane or via pop ups.
Step 1: Enable Attachments
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/enable-attachments.htm
Step 2: Add attachments
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-attachments.htm

As for an ArcGIS BLOB field type, ArcGIS applications won't be able to display this field directly on a map. You would need to use a custom [...] viewer or a third-party application to [...] view the contents of a BLOB field. (Reference)
"